# Can I use amount with plural nouns

Tags: singular-vs-plural

According to grammar, *amount* should only be used with uncountable nouns. But in the following TOEFL TPO question, it is used with plants.

Are they used incorrectly?

> Second, the production of significant amounts of ethanol would dramatically reduce the ***amount of plants*** available for uses other than fuel. For example, much of the corn now grown in the United States is used to feed farm animals such as cows and chickens. It is estimated that if ethanol were used to satisfy just 10 percent of the fuels needs in the United States, more than 60 percent of the corn currently grown in the United States would have to be used to produce ethanol. If most of the corn were used to produce ethanol, a substantial source of food for animals would disappear.

Comment: I think it's acceptable, because it refers to 'plants' in the sense 'plant material' rather than a specific number of individual plants.

Comment: Even though I know that this is sometimes said or written, it does sound a little awkward to me.  I think I'd always prefer "number of plants" (or: "amount of plant material")  It's not incorrect use, however.  You will see it, and the meaning is clear.

Comment: @KateBunting Are you agreeing with OP's claim that *amount* can cannot be used with countable nouns? Think of a random countable noun. Erm, ok, "bicycles". Let's see if Google throws up any results. [Lo and behold, it does](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22amounts+of+bicycles%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). How about ["cucumbers"](https://tinyurl.com/muzy4z86). Erm, "Penguins?". [Yep, of course](https://tinyurl.com/3t6zv8ww). I'll match your and OP's invisible rule and up to with a stick of rhubarb.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - I understand the rule to be 'amount of a substance - number of things', but I'm aware that people often ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

## 'amount' can be used with countable nouns

From [Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/amount_1):

> **Amount** is most often used with uncountable nouns: an amount of cash/space/material/food It is also sometimes used with countable nouns

It may be a rule in your curriculum or classroom to use *amount* with countable nouns as a matter of developing your habit, but that does not mean it is an accurate rule for all grammar. Often times for example, it is my experience rules in an ESL classroom are intended to cultivate habits, but not represent all nuances of grammar.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, 'plants' is an uncountable noun because in the referenced industrial usage, 'plants' are not counted by specific numbers.

> I need 10 tons of corn stalks (plants) for the herd this year.

You would not say

> I need 75,000 corn stalks for the herd this year.

I mean, you could, but it just doesn't work like that.

Agriculture, like other industries has its nuances.  For example, it would not be unusual to hear

> My nursery produces 25,000 roses (another plant) every February.

because they are sold as individual roses.

Comment: has `it's` nuances?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for the actually helpful comment!

Comment: This is incorrect.   Uncountable number is never used with a plural form.   If a noun is inherently uncountable, it has no plural form.  An example of an "uncountable noun"  is "furniture".    You cannot write "furnitures" to describe a set of  chairs, tables, and bookshelves.    "Chairs", "tables" and "bookshelves" are *countable*.

Comment: @BadZen BTW, I love the attention.  But you're wrong again.  Plants in this case is an uncountable noun, see my example.  You would not say 10 tons of potato.  Well, you could but that means something different.  It's essentially a collective noun, hence uncountable.

Comment: "Plants" is a plural form, and uncountable nouns have no plural form.  See https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/countable-and-uncountable-nouns/ for more on this, and to verify what I'm telling you - it's said there exactly the same.   "Potato" has nothing to do with this, it's obviously a countable noun.  "One potato, Two potatoes".  There is no question about the number of the noun in  the passage above, the question is about the use of "amount".

Comment: @BadZen Seriously, stop.  You weird beef with me is a disservice to readers.  My example of 100% correct.  Plants is a collective form and uncountable in this context.  Reference all you want, you're still wrong.  The text OP is referring to is completely valid.

Comment: The reference I gave you, as well as the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (2002 p. 338), which both agree that the plural form forces a counted number, are wrong?    Because you say so?   Can you provide an authoritative reference that supports your opinion, since the CGEL disagrees with you here?   (By the way, no one has argued that the text in OP is invalid, read up.)

Comment: You could have five tons of powdered or dried potato.

Comment: You could also have "three pieces of furniture", that does not make the number sense of "furniture" countable.   It does demonstrate that "tons" are countable, however.

Comment: A second (minor) issue in this answer which needs correcting: it's "herd", and not "heard".

Comment: @BadZen OMG, stop digging the hole deeper.  At this point, when you're triggered, I know I'm right.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but only when the specific potato product is known to both the speaker and listener, which is why I point out that means something different.  Your example works in a factory but not the general context OP is asking about.

Comment: @Johns-305 So if I'm a farmer awaiting a delivery of feed for my cattle and they bring more than I need, I would say "That's too much plants!" to the delivery driver (because it's uncountable in this context), but if I'm awaiting a delivery from my florist I'd say "That's too many plants!" (because it's countable in this context)? Is that right?

Comment: While I don't think this answer addresses the primary issue, I think this industrial usage idea is accurate, helpful, and very much relevant. So, I'm upvoting. Another example from the question is *fuels*, also comparable to *waters*.

Comment: @Showsni Contexts here are very nuanced.  You might say "That's too much of the plants but not enough of the insects." because the specific product would be known to both.  To the florist, you'd be more specific at the consumer level "too many roses, not enough baby's breath."  The nuance in this context is that 'plants' is a product in itself, not composed of individual specific plants.